# C# flatten a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following objects:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I have this structure:

```
[
    {
        "order_id": 1,
        "total_price": 700,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "cellphone",
                "price": 500,
                "sku": "1s4f"
            },
            {
                "product_name": "airphones",
                "product_price": 200,
                "sku": "1ar4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "order_id": 2,
        "total_price": 5000,
        "products_info": [
            {
                "name": "car",
                "price": 2500,
                "sku": "8y5t"
            },
            {
                "name": "battery",
                "price": 1500,
                "sku": "5g3g"
            },
            {
                "name": "insurance",
                "price": 1000
                "sku": "5r8f"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to the first order to be splitted to 2 orders, each one contains one item, and the second order to be splitted to 3 orders, with the same logic.
What's the best clean and readable way of doing that?

Comment: So you want the first item to be 2 orders, with the same Id, but with a single item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gven an `IEnumerable<Order>` you can use LINQ `Select` and `SelectMany`

```
var result = orders.SelectMany(o => o.Items.Select(i => new Order{
   OrderID = o.OrderID,
   TotalPrice = i.Price,
   Items = new List<OrderItem> {
        new() { Name = i.Name, Price = i.Price, SKU = i.SKU }
   }
});
```

This will flatten your items into 5 separate orders, each with a single item. I have assumed you wanted the order `TotalPrice` to match the price of the single item it now has underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is changing OrderItem and put a foreign Key in it

```
    public class OrderItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

and then query
like this `var Items=_context.OrderItem.Tolist();`